# The input is not a valid Base-64 string exception when referencing an svg from another svg

Tags: c#, svg, href

I have a c# appliation which has an SVG parser in it . When I pass the follwing svg document (SVG01) to the parser it throws an exception :

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

My svg that is going to the used in the application is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dominant-baseline="hanging">


    <image x="2.34mm" y="3.44mm" height="20mm" width="40mm" href="D:\linkedSvg.svg"/>
</svg>
```

The LinkedSvg.svg is as follows

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dominant-baseline="hanging" width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Looks like in SVG href needs to have some base:64 encoding characters right ?

IS there any other way to Link 2 svgs together ?

Comment: href takes a URL, not a file path.

Comment: how can I make it take a file path ? is there a supported element as such for svg

Comment: You can't really.  But, depending on your SVG parser, you may be able to use a `file:` URL.  Eg. try `href="file:///d:/linkedSvg.svg"`. But if that fails, it sounds like your library *might* accept Base64 Data URLs.  Eg. `href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,<your svg here encoded as base64>"`

Comment: Thanks Paul Will try that